# Front End Dropdown Field from Super Table

Tags: craft3, plugin-supertable, frontend-form

I have a single static Super Table Field with some Dropdown Fields.
Is it possible to loop through the values instead of hardcoding each one?
My hardcoded version works without problems but i think a dynamic loop is better for the future.

Here is one example: ('static' is the value of the Super Table btw.)

```
<li>
    <label for="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][fields][visibility]">Visibility:</label>
    <select name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][fields][visibility]">
      <option value="privat"{% if entry.static.visibility.value == "privat" %} selected{% endif %}>Privat</option>
      <option value="public"{% if entry.static.visibility.value == "public" %} selected{% endif %}>Public</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Would be great, if someone has a idea! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this in the same way as for a dropdown field in Craft [as described in the docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dropdown-fields.html#working-with-dropdown-field-data).

Something like this should work if `entry` is populated:

```
<li>
    <label for="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][fields][visibility]">Visibility:</label>
    <select name="fields[{{ fieldHandle }}][{{ block.id }}][fields][visibility]">
      {% for option in entry.static.visibility.options %}
         <option value="{{ option.value }}"{% if option.selected %} selected{% endif %}>{{ option.label }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
</li>
```

Comment: just that easy. Thanks!